# Is it possible to use NGraphics to draw geometric shapes on .net Forms?

Tags: c#, ngraphics

I am trying to draw some geometric shapes using [`NGraphics`](https://github.com/praeclarum/NGraphics) in a picture box on a WinForm:

```
public partial class DrawingForm : Form
{
    public DrawingForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void DrawingForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var canvas = Platforms.Current.CreateImageCanvas(new NGraphics.Size(100), scale: 2);

        var skyBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(NGraphics.Point.Zero, NGraphics.Point.OneY, Colors.Blue, Colors.White);
        canvas.FillRectangle(new Rect(canvas.Size), skyBrush);
        canvas.FillEllipse(10, 10, 30, 30, Colors.Yellow);
        canvas.FillRectangle(50, 60, 60, 40, Colors.LightGray);
        canvas.FillPath(new PathOp[] {  new MoveTo (40, 60),
                                        new LineTo (120, 60),
                                        new LineTo (80, 30),
                                        new ClosePath ()
                                    }, Colors.Gray);

        this.pictureBox1.Image = (Image)canvas.GetImage();
    }
}
```

This source code is giving the following exception:

```
Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'NGraphics.ImageImage' to type 'System.Drawing.Image'.
```

This is one problem. Another question is: is it possible to draw shapes directly on the Forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the source code for the `NGraphics` package, it looks like you should construct the `GraphicsCanvas` based on a standard `Graphics` context that you could obtain from the form.

https://github.com/praeclarum/NGraphics/blob/master/Platforms/NGraphics.Net/SystemDrawingPlatform.cs#L152

Something like this perhaps

```
var canvas = new GraphicsCanvas(this.CreateGraphics());
```

The other thing you need to do is use the `Paint` event

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var graphics = this.CreateGraphics();

    var canvas = new GraphicsCanvas(graphics);

    var skyBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(NGraphics.Point.Zero, 
        NGraphics.Point.OneY, Colors.Blue, Colors.White);

    canvas.FillRectangle(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), skyBrush);
    canvas.FillEllipse(10, 10, 30, 30, Colors.Yellow);
    canvas.FillRectangle(50, 60, 60, 40, Colors.LightGray);

    canvas.FillPath(new PathOp[] {  new MoveTo (40, 60),
                            new LineTo (120, 60),
                            new LineTo (80, 30),
                            new ClosePath ()
                        }, Colors.Gray);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but how does that go with Winforms PictureBox, or the winforms itself?

Comment: Both inherit the `Control` class, which has the CreateGraphics method - the trick is usually creating the canvas from the graphics context of the control you want to draw on.

You should not need to set the image directly, so the final line can be removed `this.pictureBox1.Image = ...`

Comment: I got an example working drawing directly onto the form (and hooked to the form's Paint event) - for other control's it's the same approach, but hooked to the control's Paint event and using a Graphics context obtained from the control